# Each function only working for even numbers

Tags: jquery, sitecore

I'm trying to get it so the class toggles for individual `div's` inside an `li` element in a loop. But only the 2nd and 4th for instance seem to work, 1st and 3rd don't toggle.

```
<ul class="card-ul">
    @foreach (Item menuLinks in folder.Children)
    {
        if (folder.GetChildren().Count > 0)
        {
            <li>
                @Html.Sitecore().Field("LinkURL", menuLinks, new { text = menuLinks.Name })
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script>
                    $(".card-ul li").each(function (index) {
                        $(this).hover(function () {
                            $(this).children("div").toggleClass("@Html.Sitecore().Field("HoverIcon", menuLinks)")
                                .toggleClass("@Html.Sitecore().Field("CircusIcon", menuLinks)");
                        });
                    });
                </script>
                <div class="@Html.Sitecore().Field("CircusIcon", menuLinks)"></div>

            </li>
        }

    }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because you're declaring the `hover` event handler in the loop, which attaches it to the same elements multiple times. This results in the odd behaviour you see.

To fix this create the event handler once, either in the `head` as in the example below, or just before `</body>`. I can see from your loop you're injecting data from the server side in to the controls, so use a `data` attribute to retrieve those. It should look something like this:

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      jQuery($ => {
        $(".card-ul li div").hover(function() {
          var $el = $(this);
          $el.toggleClass($el.data('hovericon') + ' ' + $el.data('circusicon'));
        });
      });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="card-ul">
    @foreach (Item menuLinks in folder.Children) 
    { 
      if (folder.GetChildren().Count > 0) 
      {
        <li>
          @Html.Sitecore().Field("LinkURL", menuLinks, new { text = menuLinks.Name })
          <div class="@Html.Sitecore().Field("CircusIcon", menuLinks)" data-hovericon="@Html.Sitecore().Field("HoverIcon", menuLinks)" data-circusicon="@Html.Sitecore().Field("CircusIcon", menuLinks)"></div>
        </li>
      } 
     }
  </ul>
</body>
```

Also note that, depending on what the classes you toggle actually do, it may be possible to achieve this in CSS alone, which is a far better solution.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quickly! Had a feeling it was due to being declared inside the loop. I've tried your fix but doesn't seem to toggle anything for me, trying to debug it currently. The idea being that the div class toggles showing a different icon that is set in the Sitecore CMS on the hover icon field. I tried doing this purely with CSS but couldn't work out a solution with it being able to be set via the CMS.

Comment: @Stackz18 there was misplaced `{` and `)` in my original answer. Try it now. Here's a working example, with the SiteCore references removed as I can't re-create that: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/0hjtx2bq/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, ahhh okay, that's working now when hovering over the `div`, I've just got to edit so that it works when you hover over the whole `li`, but no biggie, thanks for the help!

Comment: To do that change `$(".card-ul li div")` to `$(".card-ul li")` and `var $el = $(this)` to `var $el = $(this).children('li')`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, shouldn't that be `$el = $(this).children('div')` otherwise you're looking for a `li` inside of the `li` element? Neither have worked for me, so I'm not sure what's going on!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, stupidly had the script before the content so it was running the script on nothing, moved it and it's working now! Thanks for all the help, much appreciated!